# Replace a cell value if criteria is fulfilled

Tags: excel, vba

Hope this question finds you well. I am trying to do some testing in excel using VBA however i ran into a problem.
Below is the code i wrote but it is not working as per my expectations.

Details:

```
Me.txt_EN.Value is Employee Name

Me.cmb_S.Value is Shift

Me.cmb_M.Value is Month

Worksheet Name = Test

Userform Name is Userform1
```

Above Values would be added via userform in excel.

Here is what below code is supposed to do: Once i click on submit button in my userform1, it should first paste the value specified in Shift (Me.cmb_S.Value) in a range (It does fine until here) then if i enter "WO" as a entry (Look at the first screen shot1), the code should change the cell value with "WO".
Example: If i select "WO" for Tuesday (Tue) and Wednesday (Wed) and my shift as Evening (E), it should first fill all cells (range E32:AI32)with E and then replaces "E" with "WO" for all Tuesdays and Wednesdays.[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHffm.png)
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2swnV.png)

Below code is a bit slow and it gives me results as shown in screen shot 2, it always excludes last Tuesdays and Wednesdays (Look at 1/30/18 and 1/3/18, they should be changed as "WO")

Any help to fix this would be appreciated and also is there a way i could add a rule so the same user cannot fill this form more than once?

```
Private Sub cmd_Submit_Click()
'select worksheet
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet 
Set ws = Worksheets("RawData") 
Dim i As Integer 
Dim m As Integer 
Dim n As Integer

'find first empty row in database 
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, 
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'copy the data to the database

For i = 5 To 36 
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txt_EN.Value 
ws.Cells(iRow, i).Value = Me.cmb_S.Value 
ws.Cells(iRow, 37).Value = Me.cmb_M.Value 
Next i

For m = 5 To 29
If Me.cmb_mon.Value = "WO" Then ws.Cells(iRow, m).Value = "WO"
If Me.cmb_Tue.Value = "WO" Then ws.Cells(iRow, m + 1).Value = "WO"
If Me.cmb_Wed.Value = "WO" Then ws.Cells(iRow, m + 2).Value = "WO"
If Me.cmb_thu.Value = "WO" Then ws.Cells(iRow, m + 3).Value = "WO"
If Me.cmb_Fri.Value = "WO" Then ws.Cells(iRow, m + 4).Value = "WO"
If Me.cmb_Sat.Value = "WO" Then ws.Cells(iRow, m + 5).Value = "WO"
If Me.cmb_Sun.Value = "WO" Then ws.Cells(iRow, m + 6).Value = "WO"

m = m + 6
If m > 35 Then Exit For Else
Next

MsgBox "Data added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Added"
Unload Me
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You use

```
For m = 5 To 29
   ...
   m = m + 6 'here you increase counter by 6 
Next 'here you increase counter by 1
```

So before your last expected loop the counter (m) is already = 32 so its > then 29 so the loop ends. Thats why last days are excluded.  
 
You must change your loop a little. 
 
If row with day name is always 30 you could use something like this

```
Private Sub cmd_Submit_Click()
   'select worksheet
   Dim iRow As Long
   Dim ws As Worksheet 
   Set ws = Worksheets("RawData") 
   Dim i As Integer 
   Dim m As Integer 
   Dim n As Integer

   Dim Mon As Boolean, Tue As Boolean, Wed As Boolean, Thu As Boolean
   DIM Fri As Boolean, Sat As Boolean, Sun As Boolean
   DIM aCell as Range

   'find first empty row in database 
   iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, 
   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

   'copy the data to the database

   For i = 5 To 36 
      ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txt_EN.Value 
      ws.Cells(iRow, i).Value = Me.cmb_S.Value 
      ws.Cells(iRow, 37).Value = Me.cmb_M.Value 
   Next i

   If Me.cmb_mon.Value = "WO" Then Mon = True
   If Me.cmb_Tue.Value = "WO" Then Tue = True
   If Me.cmb_Wed.Value = "WO" Then Wed = True
   If Me.cmb_thu.Value = "WO" Then Thu = True
   If Me.cmb_Fri.Value = "WO" Then Fri = True
   If Me.cmb_Sat.Value = "WO" Then Sat = True
   If Me.cmb_Sun.Value = "WO" Then Sun = True

   For Each aCell In ws.Range("E30:AI30")
      If aCell = "Mon" And Mon Then ws.Cells(iRow, aCell.Column).Value = "WO"
      If aCell = "Tue" And Tue Then ws.Cells(iRow, aCell.Column).Value = "WO"
      If aCell = "Wed" And Wed Then ws.Cells(iRow, aCell.Column).Value = "WO"
      If aCell = "Thu" And Thu Then ws.Cells(iRow, aCell.Column).Value = "WO"
      If aCell = "Fri" And Fri Then ws.Cells(iRow, aCell.Column).Value = "WO"
      If aCell = "Sat" And Sat Then ws.Cells(iRow, aCell.Column).Value = "WO"
      If aCell = "Sun" And Sun Then ws.Cells(iRow, aCell.Column).Value = "WO"
   Next

   MsgBox "Data added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Added"
   Unload Me
   UserForm1.Show

   application.screenupdating = true 
   application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Didn't tested it so it might need some adjustments

Comment: Thanks a bunch, worked like a charm. Double thumbs up!